# Skype update error when running apt update

Tags: apt, skype

When I run `sudo apt-get update` to update the system I get this error on the bottom of the console:

```
W: GPG error: https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1F3045A5DF7587C3
W: The repository 'https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

What's going wrong with Skype? Is there any risk since the error says that the Skype repo is dangerous to use?

I use Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @DavidFoerster The core solution remains the same for fixing NO_PUBKEY issues, at least with regards to the Skype repository.  Especially in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/919522/10616) on that linked question.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

According to https://repo.skype.com/, run:

```
curl https://repo.skype.com/data/SKYPE-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add -
```

in a terminal.